# Adding spacial index to huge table Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, azure, indexing

I have a table that is really huge and I need to add spacial index for point coordinates for each record. It is a production db and data is inserting all the time. I cannot turn it off for a long time. What is the best way to add spacial indexing in that case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should help:

```
Alter Table [yourTable]
     Add newIndex int identity(1,1) NOT NULL
```

For me it gave them numbers according to insert order, and it will keep giving new numbers for next rows, i'm not using Azure thow, just regular SQL Server.

**Note:** You won't have have to stop the table for this, and it shouldn't take a lot of time (I don't know how many rows you're talking about here, but if it's less than one million it should be instanous) in any cases it's better to execute at a time the production is stopped (during a break or after everyone left) so in case shit happened you'll still have time to fix things, I'm saying that based on personnal experience !